# How to use a Twitter Bootstrap icon inside an ASP.NET Button?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How can I use a:

```
<i class="icon-etc"></i>
```

with an asp.net button?

Answer (score 19):

LinkButton, like this...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Select</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, just never tought of it! Thank you

Answer (score 10):

You may add the `<i>` tag as a value to the `LinkButton` `Text` attribute.

**e.g.**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnExcluir" runat="server" Text="<i aria-hidden='true' class='icon-remove-3'></i>" CssClass="btn btn-danger" />
```

You can even use it with a side text.

**e.g.**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnExcluir" runat="server" Text="Link Name&nbsp;<i aria-hidden='true' class='icon-remove-3'></i>" CssClass="btn btn-danger" />
```

Comment: I used this method because I needed to be able to change the text and icon from the code behind. However, I would add that in order to make it work I had to enclose the class name of the <i> element in single inverted commas, i.e. `<asp:LinkButton ID="btnExcluir" runat="server" Text="Link Name&nbsp;<i aria-hidden='true' class='icon-remove-3'></i>" CssClass="btn btn-danger" />`

Comment: Well noticed @philip-stratford, thanks! Just updated it to match your suggestion.

Comment: @Korv, I suggest to select a best answer, and this is a good one

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnExample" runat="server" Text="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-repeat'></span> Button" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" OnClick="btn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

or

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnExample" runat="server" Text="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-flash'></i> Button" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" OnClick="btn_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Regards C:

Comment: Remember to use
    asp:LinkButton
and not use
    asp:Button

The former works, the latter will not. Caught me ;)

Comment: I found using the I class most useful when using this in a gridview select button

Answer (score 0):

I have done like this.

Markup:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phButtonToLabelsAdminBox" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Spara" />
<asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Töm/Ny" />
```

CodeBehind Page_Load()

```
FixGlyph(phButtonToLabelsAdminBox, btnSave, "icon-ok")
FixGlyph(phButtonToLabelsAdminBox, btnClear, "icon-refresh")
```

And the Sub:

```
Private Sub FixGlyph(ph As PlaceHolder, btn As Button, IconClass As String, Optional CustomLabelStyle As String = "")

If btn.Visible = False Then Exit Sub
Dim g As New HtmlGenericControl
g.ID = "labelFor_" + btn.ID
g.TagName = "label"
g.Attributes.Add("for", btn.ClientID)
g.Attributes.Add("class", "" + btn.CssClass + "")
If Not CustomLabelStyle = "" Then g.Attributes.Add("style", CustomLabelStyle)
g.InnerHtml = "<i class=""" + IconClass + """></i> " + btn.Text
ph.Controls.Add(g)
btn.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;")

End Sub
```

I use ordinary asp:Button in my Markup and the only things are that to run the FixGlyph after other code that might set visible true/false for the buttons and to add the FixGlyph in the order you want the buttons to appear. Other than that, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anders Smedman, your code sure did the job.
here is the C# code if anyone needs it.

```
 private void FixGlyph(PlaceHolder ph, Button btn, string iconClass, string customLabelStye = "")
    {
        if (btn.Visible)
        {
            var g = new HtmlGenericControl();
            g.ID = "labelFor_" + btn.ID;
            g.TagName = "label";
            g.Attributes.Add("for",btn.ClientID);
            g.Attributes.Add("class","" + btn.CssClass +"");
            if (customLabelStye != "")
            {
                g.Attributes.Add("style",customLabelStye);
            }
            g.InnerHtml = "<i class='" + iconClass + "'></i> " + btn.Text;
            ph.Controls.Add(g);
            btn.Attributes.Add("style","display:none;");
        }

    }
```