# Facebook Styled ASP.NET Buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, facebook, button

I am having a problem in ASP.NET to style buttons like the Facebook Buttons, found here:
http://nicolasgallagher.com/lab/css3-facebook-buttons/

I tried using `asp:Button` with `CssClass` set, which works most of the time, except for the buttons that contain images, for example:

```
class="uibutton icon add"
```

If i use:
     Button
then things look fine, however I can't connect to the C# code without using JavaScript to do the work.

I'm hoping there is something simple I am missing (I have tried using 'background' and 'background image' in CSS with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As there's only one element it should work. Could you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Bootstrap suffers the same problem, and the only way (sort of) around it is by using a LinkButton as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352535/how-to-use-a-twitter-bootstrap-icon-inside-an-asp-net-button]).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link provided, it seems you can't use the icons with an `<input>` tag, only with `<button>` or `<a>` tags. Fortunately, `<asp:LinkButton>` will act the same as an `<asp:Button>` on the server, but render as an `<a>` tag on the client.

So try using `<asp:LinkButton CssClass="uibutton icon add" ... >` and it should work fine.