# how to use bootsrap icon on asp.net button

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, icons

hello friends i want to use Bootstrap like icons with button but when i try using it in my asp.net project the image doesnt shows can you please tell me how to use bootstrap icon with buttons i have tried this code

`<i class="icon icon-ok"><asp:Button ID="SubmitBtn" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" Text="Submit"
                                    CssClass="btn btn-small btn-primary" /></i>`

and this one too

`<asp:Button ID="SubmitBtn" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" Text="Submit"
                                    CssClass="btn btn-small btn-primary" ><i class="icon icon-ok"></i> </asp:Button>`

also i tried using this `<asp:Button ID="SubmitBtn" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" Text="Submit&nbsp;<i aria-hidden=true class=icon-ok icon-white></i>" CssClass="btn btn-small btn-primary" />`

but it dont work please someone post a solution how to make it work ???

Comment: I don't think you can you it with button, use Link

Comment: try uploading your pic to a server and then use `<asp:ImageButton ID="buttonPayPal" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" 
        onclick="buttonPayPal_Click" />`

Comment: I tried using link button it worked thank you .. But now i am not able to use the icon-white css inside the button ... i have used it but still the icon is displayed in gray color.   Note:i am using Bootstrap's css

Comment: Why are you not able to use the css? Have you tried CssClass property?

Answer (score 24):

LinkButton, like this...

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="SubmitBtn" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-small btn-primary"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i>&nbsp;Submit</asp:LinkButton>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11373500/1315626

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="button" onserverclick="Unnamed_ServerClick" class="btn btn-default " runat="server" > <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use asp:LinkButton or the HTML tag, as mentioned in the previous responses. However, if you specifically want to use asp:button for another reason, I can provide a solution for you. You can add the CSS in separate files and import them into your master page to reuse the code in multiple web forms.

```css
.btnHidden {
    background: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0rem;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-primary" onclick="<%=btnSearch.ClientID %>.click()">
    <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btnHidden" Font-Bold="true" Text="Search" />
</div>
```