# How to Add bootstrap icon to ASP.NET Button created dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a HTML button which has an icon inside the button.

[image]

HTML of button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn blue"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Save</button>
```

I need to be able to put this `<i>` code inside a button that I generate within ASP.NET. This is the code to make the button.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Id = "btnSave";
button.CssClass = "btn blue";
button.Text = "Save";
Placeholder.Controls.Add(button);
```

I saw a solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352535/how-to-use-a-twitter-bootstrap-icon-inside-an-asp-net-button/11373500#11373500), but that is for LinkButtons.

Comment: Did you try adding it to the Text property of the Button? for example: button.Text = "<i class='fa fa-check' /> Save"

Comment: i think you must create, custom control!

Comment: @JoshSiegl Html Tags in button text , show as raw html

Comment: Any reason you can't use a linkbutton? You could set the text to the icon with the character code instead if you need to. Like &#xabcd; Save

Comment: @JoshSiegl: Yes, But that icon tag is appearing as the text on the button instead of ICON.

Comment: @barzin.A: How?

Comment: @abney317: Yes, this is dynamic control and is being used at many other places with different uses.

Comment: You have a solution for a `LinkButton`. Why not switch to that one instead? You are styling the button with CSS anyways.

Comment: @JuanR : I have my reasons therefore I can't use `LinkButton`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal button if you add `runat="server"` with `onserverclick`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn blue" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_Click">
   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Save
</button>
```

Dyamically generated

```
HtmlButton hb = new HtmlButton();
hb.ServerClick += Button1_Click;
hb.Attributes.Add("class", "btn blue");
hb.InnerHtml = "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>Save";

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(hb);
```

Comment: I can't create control like this, my control is Dynamically created as I showed in my question.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I can't change my control to `HtmlButton` , because I need to use the `CommandName` property of ASP.NET Button.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. If you really need to use CommandName you can only use the aspnet Button and LinkButton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the character code to add the font-awesome icon to the button text directly.

```
button.CssClass = "fa";
button.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("&#xf00c; Save");
```

Comment: This is not working, character code is coming as text at the button.